# Video on demand requirements

Tags: video, video-streaming, netflix, on-demand

I am wondering how can Netflix get the needed upload bit rate to sustain their service. I would like to start my own Netflix-like service, what type of infrastructure, internet service I am going to need? I would like to support around 1000 users and stream dvd quality content.

Any hints would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need a Content Delivery Network. And lots of cash. Or look at a cloud video service that has it built in. Maybe NimbusHD?

Answer (score 1):

Look to Amazon AWS.  That is where Netflix gets their elasticity and speed.